# pyqgis standalone script Unable to execute algorithm Input layers do not have the same grid extent

Tags: pyqgis, saga

I created a simple pyqgis standalone script and I have some errors with some datasets and I don't know why some times the script works fine and other times the script gives an error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

that is because `SAGA algorithm SAGA FLOW WIDTH AND SPECIFIC CATCHMENT AREA 1`
 don't work correct for some datasets for other raster datasets work fine and I don't know why with the half dataset work and other not working.

and specific message in pycharm :

```
..\..\..\..\..\src\core\qgsmessagelog.cpp(45) : (QgsMessageLog::logMessage) [31ms] 2017-11-01T00:03:06 Processing[1] Unable to execute algorithm
Input layers do not have the same grid extent.
Unable to execute algorithm
Input layers do not have the same grid extent.
```

all dataset is in some srs.

I think so and for other SAGA algorithm I have similar problem .

here code :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsApplication,QgsRasterLayer
import sys
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-ltr/python/plugins')
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer(dem_uri, 'spi')
rasterLyr.isValid()
outputs_GDALOGRSLOPE_1 = processing.runalg('gdalogr:slope', rasterLyr, 1.0, True, True, False, 1.0, None)
rasterLyr1 = QgsRasterLayer(outputs_GDALOGRSLOPE_1['OUTPUT'], 'spi1')
rasterLyr1.isValid()
.....................................
outputs_SAGAFLOWWIDTHANDSPECIFICCATCHMENTAREA_1 = processing.runalg  ('saga:flowwidthandspecificcatchmentarea',rasterLyr,outputs_SAGACATCHMENTAREA_1  ['CAREA'],0, None, None)
.....................................
```

some messages in pycharm editor :

```
Parameters

Grids: No objects
Files: "C:path/to/image.tif"
Transformation: yes
Interpolation: Nearest Neighbor


loading: C:path/to/image.tif

Driver: GTiff
Bands: 1
Rows: 2523
Columns: 3864



Transformation:

x' = 393.147600 + x * 15.000000 + y * 0.000000

y' = 4564.500000 + x * 0.000000 + y * -15.000000

warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
using cellsize: 15.000000

C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\ungdal>saga_cmd ta_hydrology "Catchment Area (Parallel)"  -ELEVATION "C:\Users\usernamen\AppData\Local\Temp\processing7d1c790b04654237b47a304b19a97535\dec292515b8d4b25864383e8cd17f368\C:pathtoimagetif.sgrd" -Method 0 -CAREA "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing7d1c790b04654237b47a304b19a97535\ece26af68ad042bc8a77aa7665ec6cff\CAREA.sdat"


_____________________________________________
library path:   C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\saga\modules\ta_hydrology.dll
library name:   Terrain Analysis - Hydrology
tool name   :   Catchment Area (Parallel)
author      :   O.Conrad (c) 2001-2010, T.Grabs portions (c) 2010
_____________________________________________

Load grid: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\processing7d1c790b04654237b47a304b19a97535\dec292515b8d4b25864383e8cd17f368\
C:pathtoimagetif.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid system: 15; 252x 385y; 3933.647600x 4506.000000y
Elevation: C:pathtoimagetif
Sink Routes: <not set>
Weight: <not set>
Material: <not set>
Target: <not set>
Catchment Area: Catchment Area
Catchment Height: <not set>
Catchment Slope: <not set>
Total accumulated Material: <not set>
Accumulated Material from _left_ side: <not set>
Accumulated Material from _right_ side: <not set>
Step: 1
Catchment Aspect: <not set>
Flow Path Length: <not set>
Method: Deterministic 8
Linear Flow: no
Linear Flow Threshold: 500.000000
Linear Flow Threshold Grid: <not set>
Channel Direction: <not set>
Convergence: 1.100000
```

error message:

```
..\..\..\..\..\src\core\qgsmessagelog.cpp(45) : (QgsMessageLog::logMessage) [31ms] 2017-11-01T00:03:06 Processing[1] Unable to execute algorithm
Input layers do not have the same grid extent.
Unable to execute algorithm
Input layers do not have the same grid extent.
```

any idea how to fix that using python or pyqgis ?some pythonic way to avoid this errors ?

Comment: related to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124728/qgis-saga-channel-network-error-input-layers-do-not-have-the-same-grid-extent

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup I have read this post that solution is from SAGA gui I know how to do that using SAGA GUI my question is how to do this using python or pyqgis in standalone pyqgis script.that is a frequency problem using saga tools in pyqgis all we need to find some common solution to fix this problem

Comment: Why don't use the corresponding processing algorithm ? [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_tools.html#resampling)

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa-GeoDatup corresponding processing algorithm ?what is this ?

Comment: the link was not clearly visible, sorry : https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/grid_tools.html#resampling

Comment: @GeoDatup sorry for late,this is one option but I don't like this way because I need for all SAGA algorithms to use this module for some dataset is necessary like this case but for other dataset maybe to be unnecessary(to mean waste time algorithm) I need python programmatically way like default crs in module is an idea but I don't know how to write it :)